# retrieve with multi or

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

im creating wfp application i want to retrieve table to datagridview
with multi value selected in listbox, getting all data that selected from listbox, so the main idea
is  apply this query from sql to application

```
select * from Vwtb where firstname='' or firstaname='' or ..
```

i have tried with while loop and searched a lot  but not worked this is my code please if its something strange for you im not professional :)

```
string[] orand = { "or"+listBox1.Text };
        foreach (string sm in orand)
        {


            cn.Open();
            string select = "select * from productvw where firstname='" + sm + "'";

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cn);

            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            cn.Close();
        }
```

any type of help will be so appreciated ....

Comment: I think it would be better to get all the first names and then query once something like `select * from Vwtb where firstaname in ('','',''...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your array to a string that can be used in IN operator.for achieving that, use this extension method

```
public static  class StaticClass 
  {
   public  static string ConvertStringArrayToString(this string[] array)
    {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i=0;i<array.Length;i++)
        {
            builder.Append(array[i]);
            if(i+1==array.Length)break;
            builder.Append(',');
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in your code use it like this

```
string[] orand = { "or"+listBox1.Text };
var values=orand.ConvertStringArrayToString();     
        cn.Open();
        string select =" SELECT * FROM productvw WHERE firstname IN "+"("+values+")"
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cn);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the IN operator.

```
string command = "SELECT * FROM productvw WHERE firstname IN (@names)";

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, cn);
dataAdapter.Parameters.Add("@names", names);
```

The names would be a list of strings, `List<string>`, and would contain all the first names you want to use.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro , but how i can parameters  be used with SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: @ari you are welcome ! You don't have to add something more than the code in the answer. You add a parameter in the adapter's Parameters property. Isn't this clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM productvw  
WHERE firstname IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Start by creating a loop that generates the sql string With the values populated.